# get vanillajs value to display in vuejs model so it is accessible in method

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I want to get the array that is in vanillajs to be accessible in the vuejsmodel. I want to use this data in the generateImageList method at the bottom. Not sure what I am missing to make this work. I have tried window.collected

```js
function getData(){

const collected = [ {title:"title 1", img:"https://source.unsplash.com/random/1"},
     {title:"title 2", img:"https://source.unsplash.com/random/2"},
     {title:"title 3", img:"https://source.unsplash.com/random/3"},
     {title:"title 3", img:"https://source.unsplash.com/random/4"},
     {title:"title 3", img:"https://source.unsplash.com/random/5"},
     {title:"title 3", img:"https://source.unsplash.com/random/6"},
     {title:"title 3", img:"https://source.unsplash.com/random/7"},];



  console.log(collected);


  let data = collected;
  



      };

 
 $(document).ready(function() { 

   let app =  new Vue({
      el: "#app",
      data:{

        listi:[],
        list:window.collected 
      },
   mounted:function(){
    getData();
   this.collected=window.collected;


    
},
      methods: {
              
          toggle: function(todo){
            todo.done = !todo.done
        },
    
        generateImages(listi, index){

            var html = `<div class="row"><!-- begin row -->`;           
                html += `<div class="col-md-1">`;
                       
                        html += `<p>{list.src}</p>`;
                        html += `</div>`;   
                        html += `</div>`;

        return html;
       
      },
      }
    })

  })
```

```html
<html>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>



    <div id="app"> 
    


    

 
      <div>
          <div v-html="generateImages()">
          



          </div>


  <div class="">
            <ul id="theList"></ul>
  </div>
    </div>

<script>
```

Comment: I know I'm not supposed to make these types of comments, but I highly suggest you move off of jQuery. Vue is enough of a solution, and everything that jQuery can do is easy and practical to do in vanilla js nowadays. There a lot of old tutorials that may lead someone to believe that jQuery is still an option, but I'd highly recommend any developer to move off of it.

Comment: But relating of the question, where do you call `getData`?

Comment: it gets called in mounted

Answer (score 0):

## Scopes in JS

What you have here is a beginner problem with scopes

### Doesn't work

```js
function example() {
  // This variable is defined inside of this function
  // So if you try to access it out of this function,
  // it will throw an error and you cannot access it
  const data = [];
}

example();
console.log(data); // ReferenceError: data is not defined
```

### Works

```js
function example() {
  window.data = { hello: "world" }
}
example();

console.log(data);        // { hello: "world" }
console.log(window.data); // { hello: "world" }
```

### What you should actually do

Functions can return values, so that problems like these don't occur. Make use of it like I've shown below. I've shown a generic example, but you can use the concept in your `mounted` handler and `getData` function

```js
function example() {
  const data = [{ a: "b" }]; // Compute your data
  return data;
}

const list = example();
console.log(list)
```